# In Ansible how to disable deprecation warnings for a playbook run?

Tags: ansible

Assume I need to do a test run of a specific playbook. I don't have access to the ansible configuration files and I can't change the playbook itself (I download it from a someone's repository).
Given the above, how can I disable deprecation warnings for that test run? Is it achievable using, e.g. extra-vars?
Sample deprecation warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host 10.246.54.235
should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward
compatibility with prior Ansible releases.
```

The following code does not work in Ansible AWX (the variable is passed to the playbook with the extra-vars / -e flag):

```
"deprecation_warnings": false
```

Comment: Why cant you just ignore it? Apart from that, It's shown for a reason, if you need to test some old playbook, you should probably use a version of Ansible that's compatible. In this case, you may want to use an older version of Ansible for this specific test.

Answer (score 6):

The ways in which a configuration setting can be set are listed in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#deprecation-warnings). In this case, if you cannot use a config file your only option is to use the environment variable `ANSIBLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS`.